# Can I install IE8 without uninstalling IE10 in the process?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-10, ie8-compatibility-mode

I have run into a few cases where IE10, with Document and Browser Modes set to IE8, is unable to reproduce bugs observed in a genuine copy of IE8 on a co-worker's computer. For most IE version-specific problems, switching IE10 to IE8 mode allows me to recreate them just fine, but more than once I've had version-specific problems that only genuine IE8 can reproduce.

Is there any reasonably easy way to get IE8 on my computer without losing my IE10 installation?

(A "No" answer is better than a convoluted solution)

Comment: I've found virtual boxes the best solution for this problem in the past

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> A "No" answer is better than a convoluted solution

Well, in that case, a "No" answer is what you shall get.

No. You can't.

Just for completeness, the "convoluted" solution:

Use a VM (Virtual Machine). This is the standard solution for testing with old IE versions.

You can download pre-configured VMs for testing every IE version from Microsoft's site http://modern.ie/

Alternatively, you might want to try out http://browserstack.com/, which is an online VM provider; same VMs as you can get from modern.ie, but running on their servers via your browser, rather than running it yourself on your own hardware. It's a paid service, but extremely convenient (oh, and you can get a free 3 month subscription from modern.ie)